# How to compare and detect overlapping gameObject Prefabs using maths

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine, overlapping

For some reason i my code doesn't properly compare when an instantiated object is being overlapped.
What i want to do is, to generate random platforms with different positions and scale (X).
And since its random, it is possible of overlapping happening. So in order to solve this problem, ive tried to compare each and every platform and see if it overlaps and when it does, it will delete itself and instantiate another one.

An addition to this question is,
If i have the overlapping problem solved, is it possible to make it so the platforms are at a certain distance away from each other, for X Y and Z.

So . .
What have i done wrong ?
What can i do ?

```
void Platform_Position_Scale_Generator(int i) {

    posX[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posY[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posZ[i] = 0;

    scaleX[i] = Random.Range(minScaleRange, maxScaleRange + 1);
    scaleY[i] = 1;
    scaleZ[i] = 1;

}

void Platform_Generator(int i) {

    platformPrefabPosition[i].x = posX[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].y = posY[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].z = posZ[i];

    Instantiate(platformPrefab, platformPrefabPosition[i], Quaternion.identity);
    platformPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX[i], 1, 1);


}

// Error with this
void Detect_Collision(int i) {

    for(int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
        for(int s = f + 1; s < i; s++) {
            bool xOverlap = (posX[s] > posX[f] && posX[s] < posX[f] + scaleX[i]) || (posX[f] > posX[s] && posX[f] < posX[s] + scaleX[i]);
            bool yOverlap = (posY[s] > posY[f] && posY[s] < posY[f] + scaleY[i]) || (posY[f] > posY[s] && posY[f] < posY[s] + scaleY[i]);

            if(xOverlap && yOverlap) {
                Debug.Log("xOverlap: " + xOverlap + " yOverlap: " + yOverlap);
            }
            else {
                //Debug.Log("xOverlap: " + xOverlap + " yOverlap: " + yOverlap);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using completely random generation for something like this, as it can easily create something totally unplayable, and making it playable can be more difficult than trying a more methodical approach.

One interesting approach could be the one shown in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkGG9Umag0M

That approach is using pre-built chunks of levels manually generated to be playable, that are later randomly chosen in run-time, to create infinite levels.

Another approach could be dynamically generating a sequence of "viable" platforms.

I'm assuming this is a 2D platform game, but the same logic could apply to other types.

For example, the following sequence:

1. Add a platform on the left edge (random Y position and size, if desired).
2. Determine viable positions of the next platform to the right and vertically, taking into account both the end position of the previous platform and other things, such as jumping distance. That would give you a max position at which you can place things and still have the player make it. You can use that max  and possibly a min. distance to chose a random value between them and still have a viable platform without overlaps.
3. Repeat step 2 until you reach some end condition, such as size of level, amount of platforms, etc.

You can also add a more complex logic, such as allowing overlaps on one axis as long as there isn't any on the other axis, or a minimum separation between both. That way you could get two nearly parallel platforms, and things like that.

Other rules could be more complex, expecting an actual specific solution from the player, such as double-jumps, bouncing off walls, etc. In that scenario you could have item 2 just be one of many generation strategies from which to chose from.

This type of generation would also be much less expensive than actual instantiation and deletion in case of collisions.

**NOTE:**

If you still want to stick to 100% random generation, but guarantee gaps between platforms. Just assume an "imaginary" border surrounding the actual platform. Instead of just taking into account current real points, just add offsets to them when testing collisions.

You should be able to test intersection without physics, using something similar to what is show here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/581014/2d-collision-detection-box-intersection-without-ph.html

```
if (object1.renderer.bounds.Intersects(object2.renderer.bounds)) {
   // Do some stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight.
Just wondering. If i were to change to your way of generating plaforms without 100% random generation.
What would i have to do to my code to fit your into that logic ?

Comment: Oh, well, actually coding an entirely new implementation from scratch here would be a bit beyond the scope of a usual SO answer, plus it would greatly depend on your game specifics, as I mentioned above.
But you may find other public information out there of examples or tutorials. Such as the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkGG9Umag0M